# Error configuring TFS2018 Search Service. Any suggestions?

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to set up the TFS2018 search Service, but it reports a problem in the configuration wizard

[image]

I tried to change the user account to enable basic autentication in Serach Service and the Service Account, but always shows the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I needed to use Administrator as search service user, still using the Network service account for the service.

In this scenario, Elasticsearch service are using Network Service.